# Has anyone been successful running the new SimCity through play on Linux?

Tags: games, playonlinux

I've been able to download origin on play an Linux but it doesn't download the game (SimCity) completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org). Have a look at whatever version of SimCity you are interested in running on there, and you will see reports from users who have tried it.